# Order by last name Doubly Linked List with header in C

Tags: c, struct

firstly thank you for the attention!

How I order by the last name in Doubly Linked List with header in C?

Im a self-taught stundent trying to learn struct data.

I can make a doubly linked list. I dont know how manipulate strings in C and how can I order by de last name alphabetically.

Im tryng to be a self-taught but is being so hard to me.
Is my first time using stackoverflow for help.

This code bellow is my last project doubly linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define ELEM_LINHA 10 

typedef struct elemento{ 
    int num;
    struct elemento *ant; 
    struct elemento *prox;
}Elem;

typedef struct elemento* Lista;


Lista *Criar_Lista(){
    
    Lista *Lista_Num=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista)); 
    if(Lista_Num != NULL) 
        *Lista_Num = NULL; 
    else{ // se a alocacao deu erro
        printf("Erro"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    
    return Lista_Num;
}

int Inserir_Inicio(Lista *Lista_Num, int num){
    
    if(Lista_Num == NULL) 
        return 0;
        
    Elem *no=(Elem*)malloc(sizeof(Elem)); 
    
    if(no == NULL) /
        return 0;
    
    
    no->ant = NULL; 
    no->num = num; 
    no->prox = (*Lista_Num); 
    
    if (*Lista_Num != NULL) 
        (*Lista_Num)->ant = no; 
    *Lista_Num = no; 
    
    return 1; 
}

int Inserir_Final(Lista *Lista_Num, int num){
    
    if(Lista_Num == NULL) 
        return 0;
        
    Elem *no=(Elem*)malloc(sizeof(Elem)); 
    if(no == NULL) // Nó inesistente retorna 0
        return 0;
    
    
    no->num = num;  
    no->prox = NULL; 
    
    if((*Lista_Num) == NULL){ 
        no->ant = NULL; 
        *Lista_Num = no; 
    }
    else{ 
        Elem *aux = *Lista_Num;
        while(aux->prox != NULL){ 
            aux=aux->prox;
        }
        aux->prox = no; 
        no->ant = aux; 
    }
    
    return 1; 


void Printagem_Dinamica(int margem, int num){ 
    int aux_num=num;
    
    int q_char=1;
    while(aux_num > 0){ 
        q_char++;
        aux_num/=10;
    }
    
    char *t=(char*)malloc(q_char*sizeof(char));
    
    int i=0;
    while(i < q_char-1){ 
        t[i]='-';
        i++;
    }
    t[q_char-1]='\0'; 
    
    if(margem == 1)
        printf(" ,_.--%s--.  ", t); 
    if(margem == 2)
        printf("   `--%s--´  ", t); 
}

void Printar_Elemento(Lista *Lista_Num){
    int br[3];
    Lista aux1, aux2, aux3;
    aux1 = aux2 = aux3 = (*Lista_Num);
    
    printf("NULL\n"); 
    do{
        br[0]=0;
        while(aux1 != NULL){
            Printagem_Dinamica(1, aux1->num); 
            aux1 = aux1->prox;
            
            br[0]++;
            if(br[0] % ELEM_LINHA == 0)
                break;
        }
        printf("\n");
        
        br[1]=0;
        while(aux2 != NULL){
            printf(" ` || %d ||->", aux2->num); 
            aux2 = aux2->prox;
            
            br[1]++;
            if(br[1] % ELEM_LINHA == 0) // 2/3
                break;
        }
        
        br[2]=0;
        printf("\n");
        while(aux3 != NULL){
            Printagem_Dinamica(2, aux3->num); 
            aux3 = aux3->prox;
            
            br[2]++;
            if(br[2] % ELEM_LINHA == 0) // 3/3
                break;
        }
        
        if(br[0] < ELEM_LINHA) 
            printf("NULL"); 
        printf("\n\n");
        
    }while(aux3 != NULL); 

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int x, num=NULL, cont=0;
    Lista *Lista_Num=Criar_Lista();
    
    do{
        if(num%2 == 1){ 
            system("CLS");
            if(num != NULL) 
            if(x=Inserir_Inicio(Lista_Num, num)){ 
                Printar_Elemento(Lista_Num); 
                cont++; 
                if(cont == ELEM_LINHA){ // se esta na hora da linha ser quebrada
                    cont=0; // O contador é reiniciado
                    printf("NULL\n"); // A palavra 'NULL' aparece na nova linha
                }
            } else if(x == 0 && num != NULL){
                printf("Erro de Memória!");
            }
        }
        else{ 
            system("CLS");
            if(num != NULL)
            if(x=Inserir_Final(Lista_Num, num)){
                Printar_Elemento(Lista_Num);
                cont++;
                if(cont == ELEM_LINHA){
                    cont=0;
                    printf("NULL\n");
                }
            } else if(x == 0 && num != NULL){
                printf("Erro de Memória!");
            }
        }
        printf("INFORME UM NUMERO INTEIRO: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }while(1); 
}
```

Now I trying to find the solution for the problem, if I got I'll post here!

thanks!!

Comment: I have not understood what you mean by "last name".

Comment: How much experience do you have with sorting? Did you successfully bubble-sort an array of ints for example? Or, better, a doubly-linked list of ints?

Comment: is like user will insert the contacts, the program must place, at the moment of insertion, in the correct position. According to last name alphabetical order. Consider that there will be no repeat surname. sorry my english isnt so good.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes! But I have some problem to understand doubly-linked list of names or I dont know if I missing something important

Comment: So you can sort integers. Can you do other stuff with names and other "strings". Like reading them in, storing them in a doubly linked list. Echoing them from the list? If not, please ask a question which focuses on the first thing of that which you cannot do.

Comment: @Yunnosch I dont understand "Echoing them from the list?" I can reading them, but I cant sort string in a doubly liked list

Comment: Echo means output as you got them as input. I.e. make printf()s from the entries in your list.

Comment: Make sure that you clarify whether you are able to read in an unpredictable number of names, echo each of them right after reading, store each of them in a doubly-linked list and when inputting is done, output all of them from the list. That is the absolute minimum before thinking of sorting "strings" in C.

Comment: If I manage to store these strings, then won't it be more difficult for me to organize them?

Comment: The list in your program does not contain any strings, despite you saying _I can reading them_.